# Not able to post data to mysql from google sheet through google app script JDBC service

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to execute this code:

```
function insertDataToMySQL() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var range = "A2:D4";
  
  // Retrieve the data from the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  
  // Connect to the MySQL database using JDBC
  var url = 'jdbc:mysql://133.181.365.284:3306/mydb';
  var user = 'user';
  var password = 'mypass';
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, user, password);
  
  // Insert the data into the MySQL table
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO test (id, name, number, remark) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    stmt.setInt(1, data[i][0]);
    stmt.setString(2, data[i][1]);
    stmt.setInt(3, data[i][2]);
    stmt.setString(4, data[i][3]);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }
  stmt.executeBatch();
  
  // Close the connection
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

And getting error message:

```
Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.
```

My mysql table structure is this:
[image]

I have checked database name, table name, username, password and IP address as well but unable to figure out the issue. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Check with your website admin